# Changing lower letter to upper letter in SVG

Tags: svg

[Svg File](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtjIdnVOoJXtodZnc4-4sJ5_FNv_kw)

I am working on a graphics application where I can only use Arc, Line, cubic and Quadratic bézier. I have an SVG file, which is a bit long but I just took first few path elements to build to see the output. I wrote a small application which replaces lower letters to upper letters and produced a simple SVG file which consists upper causes and consists only four SVG commands. I have created two paths with original for and the second path with a modified version to confirm my output. Everything seems work fine excluding lower letter ‘m’. The result is not correct. I am not sure way. Any help should be very much appreciated. What mistake I am making? To see the converted version you have to uncomment the send path

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and earn your first badge also ;) ). Also, to improve the chances of getting useful answers please check [what kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The path is invalid (and so is the commented out one). commas are only allowed between two numbers so Z, M and Z, m are both invalid. Safari and Firefox both record parsing errors in their developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your SVG.

1. Your path consists of eleven subpaths. Each of the subpaths form a very thin horizontal rectangle. For example, look at the first subpath:

   M 21.52,184.48, H 91.11, v-.07, H21.54, l 0,.07 Z

   That's a rectangle that is 91px wide and 0.07 pixels high.  A rectangle that is 7/100 of a pixel high is going to be very faint at best. It is visible in Firefox, but Chrome seems to be culling it completely for some reason.
2. Your `fill` is invalid.

   ```
   fill="New_Gradient_35"
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   fill="url(#New_Gradient_35)"
   ```
3. Your path definition is invalid.  There should not be commas before a path command letter.

   ```
   M21.52,184.48,H91.11,v-.07,H21.54,l0,.07Z,
   ```

   should be

   ```
   M21.52,184.48H91.11v-.07H21.54l0,.07Z
   ```

   Chrome is a little forgiving. It will allow commas after a coordinate value, but not after a path command.  So it doesn't mind:

   ```
   M21.52,184.48,H91.11,v-.07,H21.54,l0,.07Z
   ```

   but it doesn't like the comma between the `Z` and the `M`:

   ```
   M21.52,184.48,H91.11,v-.07,H21.54,l0,.07Z,
   M ...etc...
   ```

   Firefox doesn't accept either comma.
4. You are specifying a `stroke` colour, but your `stroke-width` is `"0"`, so your stroke will not be drawn.  But perhaps that was intentional.

If you fix these issues, you get a more successful result. I'm not sure if it was what you are expecting though. It doesn't look much like a letter "m" to me.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 498.9 498.9" width="100%" height="100%">
   
    <linearGradient id="New_Gradient_35" x1="369.44" y1="1293.18" x2="137.44" y2="718.97" gradientTransform="translate(15.85 -609.22)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0.07"/>
      <stop offset="0.93" stop-color="#454d51"/>
    </linearGradient>
 
  <title>Test One</title>
  <g id="Case">
    <path fill="url(#New_Gradient_35)" stroke-width="0" stroke="red" d="M21.52,184.48H91.11v-.07H21.54l0,.07Z
    M469,147.4q1.62,0,3.21,.12l-406.4,0c.67,-.05,1.35,-.09,2,-.12l401.16,0Z
    m8.55,.76,.22,0H60.82l.56,-.1h6l-5.47,.06Z
    m1,.2,.7,.15,-419.89,0,.4,-.09,418.79,0Z
    m2.21,.5,.31,.08H185.41v-.07Z
    m1.88,.5,.37,.11H55.54l.23,-.07,426.9,0Z
    m.74,.22,.16,0,-428.69,0,.43,-.13,428.11,0Z
    m.85,.27,.47,.15H227.91l-63.75,0v0l58.44,-.08Z
    m.8,.27,.23,.08,-432.07,0,.35,-.12,431.49,0Z
    m.55,.19,.33,.12,-433.37,0,.39,-.14Z
    m.83,.31,.2,.08H51.93l.2,-.08Z" />

  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: I just realized Firefox has strict rules about syntax. Now I have modified according to Firefox syntax and it works fine with its browser. I just can’t understand how I can relative (‘m’) command to absolute (‘M’) commands. I have created two identical paths where Green path should cover Black, but that is not is case. How SVG compiler render relative path. Your help will be very much appreciated. 
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtjIdnVOoJXtodZnc4-4sJ5_FNv_kw

Comment: That's a different topic and you should ask a new question for this.